# Navigation does not go on the side and pushes product div down

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am struggling with the css on my this website I would like to set up:

[My Side](http://kaffee.gearnatic.com/kaffeevollautomat-vergleich/)

I would like to let the css look like the following.
[image]

I tried to pack the description text and the product view into one `div` container, but still the selection on the side is in its way.

What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change css this class `.faceted .model`

```
.faceted .model {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 49% !important
}
```

Add this property this class `.entry-content`

```
.entry-content{  float: left;
    width: 790px;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! You made my day! Everything works fine now!